# Layering multiple 'ForEach' statements to loop through a directory and perform actions on each file found

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csv

I've been working on this Powershell script for a good week now, and it almost works as expected.

Essentially, the script reaches into the specified directory which we have another script dropping .CSV files into, grabs the .CSV file(s) and pushes the information found into a Sharepoint list, well, that's the intention anyway. I've gotten the script to work perfectly if I manually specify the file, the issue I am having is actually getting all the .CSV files into a group, and then looping through each .CSV to pull the information out and push it into a Sharepoint list. Once done, it renames the file from .CSV to .ARCHIVED for another script to come in and re-locate after we're done with it.

I think I have, through selective (creative) troubleshooting, figured out what I am doing wrong, I just don't know how to proceed after identifying the issue.

I declare the string $Filecsv like so:

```
$Filecsv = get-childitem "Z:\" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".csv"}
```

So, this reaches into my 'Z:\' directory, and pulls all the files with .CSV extension and combines them into a table...

```
ForEach ($items in $Filecsv) {
```

And this says for each item, perform logic...

```
foreach($row in $Filecsv)
```

The only problem is, when I call $Filecsv, it is returning the list of each .CSV file in the directory like such:

[image]

And as such, when I execute the bit of code that says 'put the information into my list', only the file name is added to my Sharepoint list....

[image]

Now, I can see what's going on here, it's pulling the 'Name' from the $Filecsv table, and pushing that up to Sharepoint, however, I am not sure how to re-construct my logic so that it operates as expected because as it exists now, it should (to me anyway) work as I think it does, but I am still new to Sharepoint and am certainly missing something here.

Below, is the full code, if it helps:

```
# Add SharePoint PowerShell Snapin which adds SharePoint specific cmdlets 
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue

#start the counter at 1 to track times script has looped
$iterations = 1

# set the location where the .CSV files will be pulled from and define the 
# file extension we are concerned with 
$filecsv = get-childitem "Z:\" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".csv"} 

# for each file found in the directory
ForEach ($items in $Filecsv) {

# check to see if files exist, if not exit cleanly 
if ($Filecsv) {"File exists" + $Filecsv} else {exit}

# count the times we've looped through
"Iterations : $iterations"

# specify variables needed.  The webURL should be the site URL, not including the list
# the listName should be the list name
$WebURL = "http://SHAREPOINTURL/"
$listName = "test"

# Get the SPWeb object and save it to a variable
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity $WebURL
# Get the SPList object to retrieve the list
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]

# START deletes all items. code shows the number of items in a list, then deletes all items  
# If you don't want your script to delete items, then remove this
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite ( $WebURL ) 
$web = $site.OpenWeb() 
"Web is : " + $web.Title 

# Enter name of the List below instead of 
$oList = $web.Lists["test"]; 
"List is :" + $oList.Title 
"List Item Count: " + $oList.ItemCount 

#delete existing contents and replace with new stuff
$collListItems = $oList.Items; 
$count = $collListItems.Count - 1 
for($intIndex = $count; $intIndex -gt -1; $intIndex--) {         
"Deleting record: " + $intIndex         
$collListItems.Delete($intIndex); 
}

# END Deletes all items



# goes through the CSV file and performs action for each row
foreach($row in $Filecsv)
{
      $newItem = $list.items.Add()
      $item = $list.items.add()      
      # Check if cell value is not null in excel
      if ($row."Name" -ne $null)
            # Add item to sharepoint list.  for this one, I had to use the internal column name. 
            #You don't always have to, but I had trouble with one SharePoint column, so I did
            {$newItem["Name"] = $row."Name"}
                else{$newItem["Name"] = $row."Not Provided"}


      if ($row."Description" -ne $null)
            {$newItem["Description"] = $row."Description"}  
                else{$newItem["Description"] = $row."No Description"}

      if ($row."NetworkID" -ne $null)
            {$newItem["Network ID"] = $row."NetworkID"}  
                else{$newItem["Network ID"] = $row."No NetworkID"}
      if ($row."Nested" -ne $null)
            {$newItem["Nested"] = $row."Nested"} 
                else{$newItem["Nested"] = $row."Not Nested"}

# Commit the update, then loop again until end of file 

$newItem.Update()
}

# get the date and time from the system

$datetime = get-date -f MMddyy-hhmmtt

# rename the file 
$NewName = $items.fullname -replace ".csv$","$datetime.csv.archived"

$Items.MoveTo($NewName)

# +1 the counter to count the number of files we've looped through
$iterations ++
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the CSV files? Are they what you want on the sharepoint file, or do they list the items that you want on the sharepoint?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician The CSV files contain what information we want in the Sharepoint list. The thing is, when I specify the file by name, things work exactly as expected, so the answers below are confusing me because he is saying I am missing things. For example if I simply do: `$Filecsv = "Z:\IT.csv" ` then my code works, the information is added to my Sharepoint list, and all is good. However, doing it dynamically like so `$csvgroup = get-childitem "Z:\" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".csv"} ` breaks things. 

I am just having a really hard time figuring out why this isn't working?

Comment: I'm working on an answer and will post it shortly, but to be honest I'm not sure why your code works when you provide the file name since from what I see it shouldn't.

Comment: You and me both! My brain is fried from staring at the ISE all day. If it helps, I am using this post as a reference: 

http://sharepointcherie.blogspot.com/2014/01/import-csv-file-into-sharepoint-list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ForEach loops look redundant since they are both looping through a list of FileInfo objects. I think you want to find all the files, and for each file load it into memory and process it's contents. We'll go that route.

I have moved your SharePoint object creation out of the loop since I don't see any point to creating the object over and over for each file processed since it never references anything based on the file or it's contents. It simply makes the same object over, and over, and over.

```
# Add SharePoint PowerShell Snapin which adds SharePoint specific cmdlets 
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue

#start the counter at 1 to track times script has looped
$iterations = 1

# specify variables needed.  The webURL should be the site URL, not including the list
# the listName should be the list name
#Setup SP object
$WebURL = "http://SHAREPOINTURL/"
$listName = "test"

# Get the SPWeb object and save it to a variable
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity $WebURL
# Get the SPList object to retrieve the list
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]

# START deletes all items. code shows the number of items in a list, then deletes all items  
# If you don't want your script to delete items, then remove this
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite ( $WebURL ) 
$web = $site.OpenWeb() 
"Web is : " + $web.Title 

# Enter name of the List below instead of 
$oList = $web.Lists["test"]; 
"List is : " + $oList.Title 
"List Item Count: " + $oList.ItemCount 

#delete existing contents and replace with new stuff
$collListItems = $oList.Items; 
$count = $collListItems.Count - 1 
for($intIndex = $count; $intIndex -gt -1; $intIndex--) {         
"Deleting record: " + $intIndex         
$collListItems.Delete($intIndex); 
}

# END Deletes all items
```

Find all the CSV files, and start looping through the list of them. I removed the check to see if the file exists. You just pulled a directory listing to find these files, they really should exist.

```
# set the location where the .CSV files will be pulled from and define the 
# file extension we are concerned with 
$CSVList = get-childitem "Z:\" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".csv"} 
ForEach ($CSVFile in $CSVList) {

# count the times we've looped through
"Iterations : $iterations"
```

Now, this is different. It loads the CSV file, and processes each row in it as $row. I'm pretty sure this is what you intended to do from the start. I also changed it from If(Something -ne $null) to check for either null, or empty since either can actually exist and the later can cause you some issues. It's just a safer method in general.

```
foreach($row in (Import-CSV $CSVFile.FullName))
{
      $newItem = $list.items.Add()
      $item = $list.items.add()      
      # Check if cell value is not null in excel
      if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($row."Name"))
            # Add item to sharepoint list.  for this one, I had to use the internal column name. 
            #You don't always have to, but I had trouble with one SharePoint column, so I did
            {$newItem["Name"] = $row."Name"}
                else{$newItem["Name"] = $row."Not Provided"}

      if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($row."Description"))
            {$newItem["Description"] = $row."Description"}  
                else{$newItem["Description"] = $row."No Description"}

      if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($row."NetworkID"))
            {$newItem["Network ID"] = $row."NetworkID"}  
                else{$newItem["Network ID"] = $row."No NetworkID"}
      if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($row."Nested"))
            {$newItem["Nested"] = $row."Nested"} 
                else{$newItem["Nested"] = $row."Not Nested"}

# Commit the update, then loop again until end of file 

$newItem.Update()
}
```

I don't really understand why you are adding a new item twice, but if it works then more power to you. Then your bit to rename files when you're done with them (hey, this looks familiar):

```
# get the date and time from the system

$datetime = get-date -f MMddyy-hhmmtt

# rename the file 
$NewName = $CSVFile.fullname -replace ".csv$","$datetime.csv.archived"

$CSVFile.MoveTo($NewName)

# +1 the counter to count the number of files we've looped through
$iterations ++
}
```

I did rename a few things to make them more indicative of what they represent ($Items to $CSVFile and what not). See if this works for you. If you have questions or concerns let me know.

**Edit:** Ok, to fix the loop trying to pull each item from the current folder we reference the FullName property of it. One line changed:

```
foreach($row in (Import-CSV $CSVFile.FullName))
```

Comment: Fantastic, we're almost there. The only thing that is broken now, is that the `foreach($row in (Import-CSV $CSVFile))` piece of the puzzle is trying to pull the files from a local directory, which doesn't exist...as seen here:

http://i.imgur.com/lXt2Fj6.png

I tried creating a new variable, like so: `$CSVFULLPATH = "Z:\" + $CSVFILE` and calling it like this `foreach($row in (Import-CSV $CSVFULLPATH))`

...but that returned: `Import-Csv : Cannot open file "Z:\".`

Any ideas?

Comment: Beautiful. I'm now adding the other pieces of the puzzle into this equation such as Group Owner and such. You've helped me learn a lot @TheMadTechnician I sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

a very cursory look would suggest that you need to use $items not $filecsv in your main loop.

essentially you are looping over the contents of the $filecsv collection, so you need to look at $items.

Comment: 'ForEach ($items in $Filecsv) {' isn't that what I am doing?

Comment: you don't seem to be using the variable $items for anything.
Your second foreach loop does the same as the first, ie loop through all the files in $filecsv. Looks like you want `foreach ($row in $items)` in your second loop.

Comment: I see what you're saying, however the results are the same no matter which 'ForEach' loop I change. Here are the results: 

http://i.imgur.com/WRLMjSU.png

Comment: ForEach ($items in $Filecsv) {

foreach($row in $items)
     {
     
     }

}

Am I doing this right @ManyRootsofAllEvil ? 

I've been blindly trying combinations of your suggestion, and so far no success has been achieved.

Comment: Sorry, a little bit tired. You need to use import-csv to be able to loop thru the rows of the csv file.

Comment: I am more confused now, as the code that I have works when I specify the file manually.

`$Filecsv = "Z:\IT.csv"` 

Pushes all the information to the Sharepoint list, from the specified .CSV.

Comment: It shouldn't since (as he states) you are never importing the CSV file into memory so it never actually reads it, it just sees it as an object. It's like pointing at a car and saying "That's a car!" and sure enough, it is a car, but when somebody asks what color the seats are nobody knows because the car was never opened up to see what color they are. It's just an object as a whole, and the details are relatively unknown.